# How can I get the det of a nxnxn matrix (ie 3d matrix)? I want to determine if the rows, columns, and i guess layers are all linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is pretty self explanatory, I just want to determine if everything in the matrix is linearly independent, I would be really glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: This seems like it related to the [rank of a tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition)